# Basic facts related to Haar measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I have a compact group $G$ and continuous functions $f_1, f_2$
from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.
I have two questions related to Haar meausure.

1. Is it true that
   $$
   \int_{[0,1]}\int_G \int_G f_1(g_1)f_2(g_2)g(\theta) \ dg_1dg_2d\theta
   = \left( \int_G f_1(g_1)\ dg_1 \right)
   \left( \int_G f_2(g_2) \ dg_2 \right)
   \left( \int_{[0,1]} g(\theta) \ d\theta \right)
   $$
   holds?
2. Does Hölder's inequality hold for Haar measure, i.e. does 
   $$
   \int_G |f_1(g)f_2(g)| \ dg
   \le \left( \int_G |f_1(g)|^p\ dg \right)^{1/p}
   \left( \int_G |f_2(g)|^q\ dg \right)^{1/q}
   $$
   hold provided $1/p + 1/q =1$?

I am pretty sure they are true, but I would really appreciate a 
short justification. Thanks! (I would also appreciate a good
reference where I can find some basic facts about Haar integrals.)

Comment: Both are true, and neither is particular to Haar measures. Hölder's inequality holds for every positive measure, and the separation of integrals holds for all measures (provided the integrals make sense).

Comment: Independence is not something that has to do with Haar measure, it's just a general measure theory thing, so your first equality it trivial by definition of an iterated integral. Since your functions are compactly supported continuous ones, it's trivial that they're integrable, and so it's easy from there. Holder's inequality is a special case of Jensen's inequality on convex functions, again:  this has nothing to do with Haar measure, it's just an integral thing.